# Restore db from backup - Amazon RDS MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services

When I try to restore db from backup, on step selecting backup file I got this error:

Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_Sdk.Sfc

Failed to retrieve data for this request.

Additional information:
An exception occured while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp.fixeddrives', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

! http://prntscr.com/222cr4 "error"

Microsoft Management Studio version which I try:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio         10.50.1617.0
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio         11.0.2100.60
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio         11.0.3368.0

with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck figuring out this issue?  I have the same problem! Thanks!!